# Why do we do this.xyz inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to understand that why do we do this.xyz inside a function?

Like consider this function which we are calling like using `foo()`

```
function foo() {
 this.value = "Shivom"
 console.log(this.value) //Shivom
 console.log(value) //Shivom
}
```

And alternate for this could be

```
 function foo() {
 value = "shivom"
 console.log(this.value) //shivom
 console.log(value) //shivom
}
```

Similarly, When In react I was using websocket someone asked me to do

```
class cryptoTicker extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
     this.socket = openSocket('https://coincap.io');

    let updateCoinData = [...this.props.cryptoLoaded];
      this.socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.socket.disconnect();
}
```

Instead of doing something like this

```
 var socket;
class cryptoTicker extends Component {
       componentDidMount() {
         socket = openSocket('https://coincap.io');

        let updateCoinData = [...this.props.cryptoLoaded];
          socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {

      componentWillUnmount() {
        socket.disconnect();
    }
```

**[Question:]** So when and why do we use this.xyz inside a function? if someone can please explain me using the given two example above?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your `Underfined` in your first `foo`, it displays "Shivom" as expected for me.

Comment: The basics of OOP… if you just have one global `var`, you can only have one instance of the component. If you store the value on `this` (the specific instance), you can have many independently acting instances.

Comment: explaining `this` in javascript is hard to accomplish in a short answer. Even seasoned devs get it wrong (me included!). I would highly recommend reading this [chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md) from You don't know JS.

Comment: @dubes While the intricacies of Javascript's `this` implementation are a bit… unusual, they're fairly straight forward once you get that it's determined at call time vs. construction time, as most other languages do it. And the basic usage of OOP doesn't change in Javascript.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the undefined was coming after both the logs, confused it with `this.value` (updated the comment)

Comment: @dubes that was seriously motivating, Thanks for sharing link

Comment: @deceze Can you please explain this in details in the answer section?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a nutshell:

```
var foo;

function bar(baz) {
    foo = baz;
    console.log(foo);
}
```

You can only have *one* `foo` value ever in your program this way. It's a *singleton*/global value.

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = undefined;
    }

    bar(baz) {
        this.foo = baz;
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
}

let a = new Foo;
let b = new Foo;

a.bar(42);
b.bar('fortytwo');
```

Using classes and object and setting properties on individual objects (`this`) allows you to have multiple independent instances of an object/value. That's the basis of OOP.